# Android 8.1.1, Serial COM port, performance issue

Tags: android, android-studio, serial-port

My partner is working on an Android App for the past year via Android Studio, he setup serial COM port via USB to control and transfer data on 115200 BAUD rate. The Android Phone is Hammer Energy (upper-middle spec I believe) and we noticed a reception issue in which ASCII based data goes astray. (we tested on two mobile device of the same make and model)

I have approx 200 ASCII streaming into Android App every 250mSec (logging data from a device). I use \n as end of frame. After several frames, ASCII seems to mutate or mangled up.

We tested it on two 3rd party app (serial terminal) and found a similar problem, which suggests something in Android not up to the task.

We tested on Window serial and found no evidence of the issue.

We plan to test on Nexus 6P (Android 9) and reduce BAUD rate, later on, has anyone experienced this issue before, and what measure to resolve it?, is there something we can do in the Android system to boost serial performance or modify COM reception buffer

Comment: This sounds to me as if the clocks of the two devices communication with each other don't align. So one devices 115200 BAUD is slightly faster then the other ones. If this is the problem is should get better when moving to lower BAUD rates because the tolerances get bigger.

Comment: How to determine the nearest BAUD that works reliably, is there something in android to tell us?